# Can I add the Twig file type to Linux?

Tags: html, mime-types, file-manager, file-opening, xdg

I generally give Twig files a "twig" extension.  As I understand it these Twig files are usually recognised as HTML like files by Linux using some sort of scan algorithm.  So Nemo for example represents these files with a web icon and clicking on properties shows the file type as "Text (text/html)".  However sometimes when there is no actual HTML near the top of the file Linux recognises the file as plain text instead.  On such files I tried adding a HTML comment as the first line:

```
<!-- Twig file -->
```

Which works OK for Twig macro files, but not for regular templates as it causes an error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Twig_Error_Syntax' with message 'A 
template that extends another one cannot have a body in "std.twig" at line 
1.' in /var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Parser.php:379 Stack trace:
...
```

I know that it is possible to put a "html" extension after the "twig" extension, so the full file name is for example:

```
foo.twig.html
```

But that is cumbersome.

So I was wondering if instead it is possible to give Linux (Mint in my case) a new file type, and perhaps have a different icon in Nemo from either the text or HTML icons?

Comment: @don_crissti If you're defining a new MIME type, call it `text/x-twig`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom mime type e.g. `text/x-twig` (and - optionally - use a custom icon<sup>1</sup> for that particular mime type) via a [new source xml file](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/shared-mime-info-spec/latest/ar01s02.html):

```
~/.local/share/mime/packages/text-x-twig.xml
```

with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <mime-info xmlns='http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info'>
  <mime-type type="text/x-twig">
    <comment>twig files</comment>
    <glob pattern="*.twig"/>
    <icon name="text-x-twig"/>
  </mime-type>
 </mime-info>
```

then update your mime database

```
update-mime-database ~/.local/share/mime
```

---

<sup>1:Keep in mind that the "icon name" must match the actual icon name(s) sans extension from your icon theme; default location for mime type icons is `/path/to/your/icon/theme/${SIZE}/mimetypes` (where sizes are e.g. `16x16`, `24x24` etc so for each size you should have a corresponding icon unless you opt to use a `svg` icon for all sizes)</sup>

Comment: I don't have a XDG_DATA_HOME variable.  I do have a XDG_DATA_DIRS variable which leads to two icon directories /usr/share/cinnamon/icons and /usr/share/icons whose contents are too numerous to list in this comment.

Comment: @tyebillion - just replace that with _the actual path to your icon theme_ e.g. `/usr/share/icons/Faenza/24x24/mimetypes`; if you don't use a custom icon set i.e. if you use the default icon set from upsteam you'll have to create a custom icon theme (which _inherits_ the theme from upstream) and add your icon.

Comment: I guess that "gnome" is my theme, but there is also a "Mint-X" directory and others in /usr/share/icons.

Comment: @tyebillion - you don't know what icon theme you're using ? If you're on `gnome` run `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme` in a terminal. If you're on cinnamon I suspect it's the same only replace `gnome` with `cinnamon` not sure though... and other DEs, I don't know.